# Plotting GeoJSON data on map using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geojson

We are developing the portal in which we are using Arcgis javascript APIs.The requirement in our project is one of the weather provider is going to publish the webservice which will return the weather data in the geoJSON format.geoJSON will contain geometry(point,line,polygon etc)
Which is the efficient way to plot the the features on the arcGIS map?

Comment: Full example here http://www.geothread.net/importing-geojson-data-in-arcgis-javascript-maps/

Answer (score 2):

you can find an extension for the JSAPI to load native GeoJSON in Esri's Github organization.  hope its helpful!

https://github.com/Esri/geojson-layer-js